# implement Backpropagation from scratch with gradient checking|| error during graident checking

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, backpropagation

#Implementing Forward propagation, Backpropagation and Gradient checking
#code to compute forward propogation based on computational graph

```
    def forward_propagation(x, y, w):
                '''In this function, we will compute the forward propagation '''
                # X: input data point, note that in this assignment you are having 5-d data points
                # y: output varible
                # W: weight array, its of length 9, W[0] corresponds to w1 in graph, W[1] corresponds to w2 in graph,..., W[8] corresponds to w9 in graph.  
                # you have to return the following variables
                # exp= part1 (compute the forward propagation until exp and then store the values in exp)
                # tanh =part2(compute the forward propagation until tanh and then store the values in tanh)
                # sig = part3(compute the forward propagation until sigmoid and then store the values in sig)
                # we are computing one of the values for better understanding
                
                val_1= (w[0]*x[0]+w[1]*x[1]) * (w[0]*x[0]+w[1]*x[1]) + w[5]
                exp = np.exp(val_1)
                tanh = np.tanh(exp + w[6])
                val_2= ((np.sin(w[2]*x[2]))*((w[3]*x[3])+(w[4]*x[4])))+w[7]
                sig = sigmoid(val_2)
                y_pred = tanh+sig*w[8]


            
            
            # after computing part1,part2 and part3 compute the value of y' from the main Computational graph using required equations
            # write code to compute the value of L=(y-y')^2 and store it in variable loss
            loss =pow(y-y_pred,2)
            # compute derivative of L  w.r.to y' and store it in dy_pred 
            dy_pred = -2 * (y-y_pred)
            # Create a dictionary to store all the intermediate values i.e. dy_pred ,loss,exp,tanh,sigmoid
            # we will be using the dictionary to find values in backpropagation, you can add other keys in dictionary as well
            
            forward_dict={}
            forward_dict['exp']= exp
            forward_dict['sigmoid'] = sig
            forward_dict['tanh'] =tanh
            forward_dict['loss'] = loss
            forward_dict['dy_pred'] = dy_pred
            
            return forward_dict
```

#code to compute backward propogation based on computational graph
backward propogation

```
    def backward_propagation(x,y,w,forward_dict):
        '''In this function, we will compute the backward propagation '''
        # forward_dict: the outputs of the forward_propagation() function
        # write code to compute the gradients of each weight [w1,w2,w3,...,w9]
        # Hint: you can use dict type to store the required variables 
        # dw1 = # in dw1 compute derivative of L w.r.to w1
        dw1 = forward_dict['dy_pred']*(1-(math.pow(forward_dict['tanh'],2)))*forward_dict["exp"]*2*((w[0]*x[0])+(w[1]*x[1]))*x[0]
        # dw2 = # in dw2 compute derivative of L w.r.to w2
        dw2=forward_dict['dy_pred']*(1-(math.pow(forward_dict['tanh'],2)))*forward_dict["exp"]*2*((w[0]*x[0])+(w[1]*x[1]))*x[1]
        # dw3 = # in dw3 compute derivative of L w.r.to w3
        dw3 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*(forward_dict['sigmoid']*(1-forward_dict['sigmoid']))*w[8]*((w[3]*x[3])+(w[4]*x[4]))*math.cos(x[2]*w[2])*x[2]
        # dw4 = # in dw4 compute derivative of L w.r.to w4
        dw4 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*(forward_dict['sigmoid']*(1-forward_dict['sigmoid']))*w[8]*math.sin(x[2]*w[2])*x[3]
        # dw5 = # in dw5 compute derivative of L w.r.to w5
        dw5 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*(forward_dict['sigmoid']*(1-forward_dict['sigmoid']))*w[8]*math.sin(x[2]*w[2])*x[4]
        # dw6 = # in dw6 compute derivative of L w.r.to w6
        dw6 = forward_dict['dy_pred']*(1-(math.pow(forward_dict['tanh'],2)))*forward_dict["exp"]
        # dw7 = # in dw7 compute derivative of L w.r.to w7
        dw7 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*(1-(math.pow(forward_dict['tanh'],2)))
        # dw8 = # in dw8 compute derivative of L w.r.to w8
        dw8 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*(forward_dict['sigmoid']*(1-forward_dict['sigmoid']))*w[8]
        # dw9 = # in dw9 compute derivative of L w.r.to w9
        dw9 =forward_dict['dy_pred']*forward_dict['sigmoid']
        
        
        backward_dict={}
        #store the variables dw1,dw2 etc. in a dict as backward_dict['dw1']= dw1,backward_dict['dw2']= dw2...
        backward_dict['dw1']= dw1
        backward_dict['dw2']= dw2
        backward_dict['dw3']= dw3
        backward_dict['dw4']= dw4
        backward_dict['dw5']= dw5
        backward_dict['dw6']= dw6
        backward_dict['dw7']= dw7
        backward_dict['dw8']= dw8
        backward_dict['dw9']= dw9
    
        
        
        return backward_dict  

def gradient_checking(x,y,w,eps):
    # compute the dict value using forward_propagation()
    # compute the actual gradients of W using backword_propagation()
    forward_dict=forward_propagation(x,y,w)
    backward_dict=backward_propagation(x,y,w,forward_dict)
    
    #we are storing the original gradients for the given datapoints in a list
    
    original_gradients_list=list(backward_dict.values())
    # make sure that the order is correct i.e. first element in the list corresponds to  dw1 ,second element is dw2 etc.
    # you can use reverse function if the values are in reverse order
    
    approx_gradients_list=[]
    eps=0.0001
    w = np.ones(9)*0.1
    #now we have to write code for approx gradients, here you have to make sure that you update only one weight at a time
    #write your code here and append the approximate gradient value for each weight in  approx_gradients_list
    for i in range(len(w)):
      w_plus =w.copy()
      w_plus[i]=w_plus[i]+eps
      Loss1=forward_propagation(x,y,w_plus)['loss']
      w_sub = w.copy()
      w_sub[i]=w_sub[i]-eps
      Loss2=forward_propagation(x,y,w_sub)['loss']
      approx =(Loss1-Loss2)/(2*eps)
      approx_gradients_list.append(approx)
    gradient_check_value =[]
    for i in range(len(w)):
      num = np.linalg.norm(original_gradients_list[i] - approx_gradients_list[i])
      den = np.linalg.norm(original_gradients_list[i]) + np.linalg.norm(approx_gradients_list[i])
      diff = num / den
      
      gradient_check_value.append(diff)
      
    
    return gradient_check_value
```

I am trying to implement backpropogation for below graph from scratch. When i try to run grader function forward and back ward propogation returns true. However, While running grader function on gradient_checking function, I am getting the below error.

```
def grader_grad_check(value):
    print(value)
    assert(np.all(value <= 10**-3))
    return True 

w=[ 0.00271756,  0.01260512,  0.00167639, -0.00207756,  0.00720768,
   0.00114524,  0.00684168,  0.02242521,  0.01296444]



  eps=10**-7
    value= gradient_checking(X[0],y[0],w,eps)
    grader_grad_check(value)
([0.9033700837499321, 0.9033700856470759, 1.0, 0.9950783883268165, 0.9950783883310051, 0.1755656033519971, 0.23240434925625725, 0.7442376971131373, 0.03845869617360365], 0.03845869617360365)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-59-a4c2d0b40187> in <module>()
      9 eps=10**-7
     10 value= gradient_checking(X[0],y[0],w,eps)
---> 11 grader_grad_check(value)

<ipython-input-59-a4c2d0b40187> in grader_grad_check(value)
      1 def grader_grad_check(value):
      2     print(value)
----> 3     assert(np.all(value <= 10**-3))
      4     return True
      5 

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXgnY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for use "w = np.ones(9)*0.1"
because weights have already initialized and passed onto "gradient_checking" function.
use this code after for loop,

```
original_gradients_list=np.array(original_gradients_list)
approx_gradients_list=np.array(approx_gradients_list)
numerator = np.linalg.norm(approx_gradients_list - 
original_gradients_list)
denominator = np.linalg.norm(approx_gradients_list ) + np.linalg.norm( 
original_gradients_list)   
gradient_check_value = numerator / denominator 
return gradient_check_value
```